# Rails order by date-time and distance

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In Rails I have an event table. I want to perform following type of ordering to my events while showing it to users on index page.

1. I want to find all events nearby a location (I am using Geocoder for that) then I want to order all these nearby events according to nearest date to current date.
   I am using following code for it: `Event.near(center_location).where("started_at <= ?", Date.today).reorder("started_at DESC")`
2. I want to show all rest of the events ordered by distance.

I have the code `Event.with_distance_to(center_location).limit(limit_of_search).reorder("#{'distance'} ASC")`

My problem is I want to perform second step on rest of the events left after first step
Please suggest
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you get all and make your first list with ("started_at <= ?", Date.today), and then return all - the_first_set for the second part?

Comment: @JoeEssey yes i can do that. Can u suggest code?

Comment: Adt, did the code help you accomplish your goal?  Would you please accept it if so?

Comment: @JoeEssey indeed, I was testing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
all_events = Event.all
nearby_events = all_events.where("started_at <= ?", Date.today).reorder("started_at DESC")
other_events = (all_events - nearby_events).limit(limit_of_search).reorder("#{'distance'} ASC")
```

If you want to append them back together to return as a single array:

```
return nearby_events + other_events
```